# Cannot create a MySQL procedure with LOOP

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

SOLVED:

This works:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_tables_from_specified_database;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database(IN dbname CHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblname CHAR(50);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = dbname COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO tblname;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @database_name = dbname;
        SET @table_name = tblname;
        SET @sql_text = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @database_name, '.' , @table_name, ';');      

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;

    SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL drop_all_tables_from_specified_database('test');

DROP PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database;
```

---

I am trying to create a procedure that deletes all tables inside a database. I have saved this code inside a file tear-down.sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE table_to_drop VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='test';

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO table_to_drop;
        IF done:
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        DROP TABLE `test`.table_to_drop;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

When I then do inside MySQL command line tool:

```
mysql> source tear-down.sql
```

I get a massive error:

[image]

I don't understand the error I get and I cannot figure out what's wrong. Anybody can spot an error in this procedure?

EDIT:

My current code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_all_tables_from_specified_database;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database(IN dbname CHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblname CHAR(50);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = dbname;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO tblname;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        DROP TABLE dbname.tblname;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL drop_all_tables_from_specified_database('test');

DROP PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database;
```

Now it runs ok but it doesn't delete the tables. I get this response:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will need to set an alternative `DELIMITER`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE table_to_drop VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='test';

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO table_to_drop;
        /* This might need to be 'IF done <> FALSE THEN' */
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        DROP TABLE `test`.table_to_drop;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That helped a bit but now I get different, smaller error. I don't see any syntax error there? Check my updated question, please.

Comment: Apparently I am using some reserved words? I don't see any.

Comment: @RichardKnop Didn't notice your `IF` syntax was messed up. Use `IF condition THEN`, rather than `IF condition:`. See above.

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the same error though after fixing the if statement.

Comment: @RichardKnop I still see the `:` in your most recent revision. The `IF` statement does not terminate with a `:`. Should just be `IF done <> FALSE THEN LEAVE read_loop;`

Comment: Can you take a look at my question. I have updated it with my latest code which runs ok (but with some collation warning). But it doesn't delete the tables.

Comment: @RichardKnop I see you're trying to use the parameter `dbname` as a table or database symbol name. I don't think that actually works. It could be used as a parameter to the WHERE clause as you did when declaring the cursor, but I don't think you can use it as you are trying to.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I have solved this with a little hack. Now it works. Check my updated question. On the top I posted working code which deletes all tables in a database based on parameter.

Comment: @RichardKnop Yep that will do it. Just be sure you're never retrieving or passing values that could leave that open to SQL injection. That's exactly the reason SPs and prepared statements don't permit the use of input variables as symbols! :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `IF done THEN` not `IF done:` . Also done variable does not get updated so you might get an infinite loop in there. Take a look at `fetch cursor into`.

Comment: I have fixed that already. Check my updated question. Still getting the same error.

Comment: That worked fine for me except I made one change, probably mysql version issue. I changed the following:
`CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables_from_specified_database`
to
`CREATE PROCEDURE test.drop_all_tables_from_specified_database`